# filenet with jboss ,code is working in standalone java code but not in JBoss

Tags: jboss7.x, filenet

Issue at line:

```
connection = Factory.Connection.getConnection("filenetuat:9080/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM"); 
    Subject sub = UserContext.createSubject(connection,"c2l.user", "$up3r2015","FileNetP8WSI");
```

The above code is working in standalone java code but not in JBoss :

refer below for error log:

Note : 
Previously we were getting :

> No properties file: users.properties or defaults:
>   defaultUsers.properties found

We have solved this issue by doing some changes in standalone.xml file of Jboss by ref below link: 
https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/mukeshghildiyal/2012/01/09/enabling-the-users-and-roles-in-jboss7-and-adding-admin-console-restriction

We need to know , to solve the “The user is not authenticated.” Do we need to do some changes in jboss (we are using jboss version 7) ?

log:

```
12:00:26,935 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-1 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-985873369)) [INFO] Recieved an object message with title saveJobRunLogService

12:00:26,948 INFO  [stdout] (org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#2920964e-1) [ERROR] Encountered an error executing the step

12:00:26,948 INFO  [stdout] (org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#2920964e-1) com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0040E: E_NOT_AUTHENTICATED: The user is not authenticated.
```

Comment: Did you figure out the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke `UserContext.get().pushSubject(subject);`

before you get OS instance.